# Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app (XCode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode7.3

I' getting the error `Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app yet they are identical` and the error is indeed showing me that the SHA1 Hash for `Embedded Binary Signing Certificate` vs the SHA1 Hash for `Parent App Signing Certificate` are not the same. My app has a bunch of targets. In addition to the App, there are targets for a Daily View, Watch Kit and Watch Kit Extension. Here's what I have done (using cleans between each of these and multiple XCode restarts):

1. Went to preferences and pressed 'download all' for the relevant
   account
2. Deleted the account & relogged in and redownloaded all certificates
3. Check all teams in the target to confirm they are all consistent and correct
4. Switch each team in the 'General' tab to `None` and then back to the team

None of this has corrected or changed the error I'm receiving. What else should I try?

Also here's what my error looks like:

[image: error]

Comment: What if you add `--deep` to the code signing flags in *Build Settings*?

Comment: @Droppy Thanks for the suggestion. Can you send a link to explain more about this? I have not heard about this and am not finding much on Google.

Comment: hello how you solved ? I Your Same problem and I'm not able to Solve

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the derived data (Window > Projects > Delete button) did the trick.

Comment: hello how you solved ? I Your Same problem and I'm not able to Solve